# how to simulate rolling dice animation for windows phone 8.1 using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, direct3d

I want to create a 3d rolling dice animation for Windows phone 8.1/10 in C#. What will be the best way to do it. Can we do using expression blend?

Comment: No, 3D operations are not possible with XAML. You might get something to look sort of like a roll, but the overhead to get it working will be impossibly complex and expensive to execute. You must use Direct3D. If you are a C# developer, you can look into SharpDX. What yo uare wanting cannot be solved with WinRT-XAML as, unlike Silverlight, there is no 3D engine built into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it might be to use DirectX. You could use XAML and do it in Blend, but you might hit some roadblocks, since XAML is better suited for controls and 2D graphics than 3D modelling. Direct3D would give you best results and you could use it with C# with either SharpDX or perhaps Unity3D in a `SwapChainPanel`, but you might find it requiring more effort than you're willing to invest in it. In that case you could choose to render it as a video in a 3D modeling app. You could probably also fake it by rendering a sequence of dice frames into an animated gif or png and bounce an animated image around the screen.